# Converter query SQL para LINQ

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, linq

Como ficaria essa query SQL convertida para LINQ:

```csharp
"SELECT SUM(valor_negocio) valor_negocio, " +
        " MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(MONTH(data_inicio), '%m')) mes," +
        " STATUS" +
        " FROM negocio" +
        " WHERE data_inicio BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2017/12/31'" +
        " AND id_empresa = "  + idEmpresa +
        " GROUP BY MONTH(data_inicio), STATUS, mes";
```

preciso que o resultado seja o seguinte:

```csharp
valor_negocio   mes         STATUS
---------------------------------------------
1500.00         January     Fechado
1260.00         February    Fechado
500.00          March       Fechado
1300.00         May         Fechado
1500.00         June        Fechado
1000.00         July        Fechado
3800.00         August      Fechado
0.00            September   Contato
3000.50         September   Em andamento
1000.00         September   Fechado
500.00          September   Perdido
5500.00         October     Em andamento
7100.00         October     Fechado
500.00          November    Em andamento
400.00          November    Fechado
```

Comment: Qual é o banco?

Comment: o banco é Mysql

Answer (score 1):

Alessandre, para definir a expressão Linq, você precisa ter acesso à tabela, através de um DbContext ou algo parecido.

Mas assumindo que haja uma variável `db` com o acesso e uma `Tabela`, o código pode ficar assim:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
...
DateTimeFormatInfo dTFI = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
var resultado =
    db.Tabela
    .Where(n => n.data_inicio >= new DateTime(2017,1,1)
                && n.data_inicio <= new DateTime(2017,11,30)
                && n.id_empresa == 1)
    .GroupBy(n => 
                new { 
                    mes = n.data_inicio.Month,
                    STATUS = n.STATUS },
             n => n.valor_negocio,
             (g, n) =>
                new {
                    valor_negocio = n.Sum(),
                    mes = dTFI.GetMonthName(g.mes),
                    STATUS = g.STATUS });
```

Comment: Arão, como pegar o nome do mes, na minha tabela só um o campo data_inicial

Comment: deu erro nessa parte: n.Sum(); nao encontrou o Sum();

Comment: @alessandremartins, o nome do mês você pode pegar usando DateTimeFormatInfo.GetMonthName (como é um método não static você precisa primeiro instanciar a classe DateTimeFormatInfo, e daí você pode usar o método GetMonthName, utilizando como parâmetro o número do mês.

Comment: Quanto ao Sum(), ele está no System.Linq, então, se você tiver referenciado a assembly e usado o using com ele, não deveria estar dando erro.

Comment: @alessandremartins, fiz os ajustes no código para te ajudar a formatar os dados direito. É importante também você validar os dados que vêm do BD para compatibilizar com as operações que você fizer no código.

Comment: o tipo da variavel estava decimal, mudei para float e o Sum() parou de dar erro, porem, deu outro erro: Unknown column 'GroupBy1.K2' in 'field list', estranho, ele esta esperando que tenha esse campo...